# Unable to set header in redirect()->away()

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, mailchimp, laravel-5.1

I want make a `GET` request to Mailchimp after receiving access token.

Here is my code:

`return redirect()->away('the url', 302, ['Authorization' => "OAuth $accessToken"]);`

This is not setting the header.
I'm receiving the access token properly. I'm also able to successfully make a `GET` request via postman.
I've also tried `redirect()->to()`. Still no luck.

**EDIT:**

I've also tried sending curl request:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'the url'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization' => 'OAuth ' . $accessToken]);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The curl request gives the following error:
`{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Unable to load login and user"}`

Please note that the same request with the same header from postman is returning proper result.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: how can you make request with redirect. it should be with curl or ajax !!!

Comment: I tried that too :)
Here is the curl request:

`$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'the url'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization' => 'OAuth' . $accessToken]);

$result = curl_exec($ch);`

This gives:
`{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Unable to load login and user"}`

Comment: please post the code properly if you really want help.

Comment: My bad. I pressed enter, and it posted instead of going to the next line :P

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with the curl request I'm making. But I managed to successfully send the request using https://github.com/nategood/httpful

I would like to know what is wrong with the curl request though.

Comment: can post it in your question properly not in comment !!!!